# How to get longest lenght of 2 columns in multiple rows

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

**Hello I need to finish some excel sheet for school and I am having real difficulties.** 
I would need to find longest **FULL** name from table like this. The requirements are that I can **NOT** create another column for making

> =Len(A1)+Len(B1)

and then compare just that column for example. So the solution should be **only** in **1 row of "code"**.

```
 |   A  |     B     |          C
1| adam |   brown   | The longest name is:
2| eva  |  jameson  |    john startstky
3| john |  startsky |
```

Any help very appriciated.
I already tried

> =INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(MAX(LEN(A1:A3)),LEN(A1:A3),0))

But that only searches through 1 column and does not work with multiple columns.

***Note:***

I am not skilled in excel that much but here is what I think should work. I just have no clue how to do something like this in excel.

```
string longestName
For each row
  if(A[index of row].lenght+B[index of row].lenght > longestName.lenght)
     longestName = A[row].tostring+" "+B[row].tostring
```

I would also like to avoid any programing in C or basic (I am not sure which language excel supports).

***Edit:*** The code part is only hint for you to understand my thinking procces. I know you cant apply code like this into formula...

Comment: Please comment when you downvote. Thank you

Comment: I didn't downvote but, I guess it has something to do with [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Oh like the homework thing ? Oh ... Okey it is not a homework. It is a part for my project on university which took me realy long time to solve. And I even was not able to solve it myself. So I would say that would be inapropriet downvote.

Comment: Just assumptions on my side, I hope the "downvoter" provide his/her feedback based on the link I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will need two Index function concatenated to get your return.  We also need to use Array Forms of MATCH to find the longest concatenation.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$3,MATCH(MAX(LEN(A1:A3 & " " & B1:B3)),LEN(A1:A3 & " " & B1:B3),0)) & " " & INDEX($B$1:$B$3,MATCH(MAX(LEN(A1:A3 & " " & B1:B3)),LEN(A1:A3 & " " & B1:B3),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit Mode instead of Enter.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if in C1, and C2 and C3 you have :

```
=LEN(A1 & B1)
=LEN(A2 & B2)
=LEN(A3 & B3)
```

then in D1 type this formula :

```
=INDEX(A1:B3;MATCH(MAX(C1:C3);C1:C3;0);1) & " " & INDEX(A1:B3;MATCH(MAX(C1:C3);C1:C3;0);2)
```

You will get

Comment: OP Stated that the use of a Helper Column is not allowed: `The requirements are that I can NOT create another column for making`

Comment: OK. Then an array formula is better